# Determine Script Authorization Requirements

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script associated with a spreadsheet which requests Authorization.  When granted and I look at the Permissions associated with my account the script has the following:

```
Has some account access, including Google Docs
    Google Docs
        View and manage your documents in Google Drive
        View and manage your spreadsheets in Google Drive
    Additional access
        View and manage your forms in Google Drive
```

I am surprised it is going to this level as all the function calls I am seeing are either getting an active item or getting the sheet by name (not the file, a tab inside the file).  Outside of an HTML service form, there is nothing I see which should call a Google Form item.  Nor do I see anything about a Doc.  Just Spreadsheet items.

Is there any way to determine where the various authorized access items are IN the code without trial and error?

Comment: not sure if this helps, but have you checked the scripts [authorization page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts)?

Comment: I have checked the page you linked to, @noogui but it isn't helping me determine what functions are looking for the permissions, such as the Forms.  Best I can tell it SHOULD only be looking at the spreadsheet file itself and not all Docs and Spreadsheets in the Drive.